# Large array declaration with gcc and its problems

Tags: c, memory-management

I was writing a code which requires a **large 'int'  array to be allocated (size of 10^9**).
While doing so i faced several issues and after reading stuff on Google i came to following conclusions of my own. Can someone see this and point out if i am missing some thing and also suggest a better way to do this.

*(Machine config: VM machine Ubuntu 10.4,gcc 4.4.3 , 32bit, 2GB ram(though my host machine as 6gigs)*

1.I declared the array as **'unsigned long int' with size 1*10^9.** It didn't worked as on compiling the code i got the error *'array size too long'*.
So i searched for this and finally realized that i cant allocate that much memory on stack as my **physical memory was 2 GB.**( *i had already tried allocating the array as global variable which would allocate them in global area instead of stack but the same error*)

1. *So i tried allocating the same amount of memory using 'malloc' but again got the error with 'malloc' this time 'Cannot alllocate memory'*.

**So after doing all this my understanding/problems are as follows:**

3- I can't allocate that much memory be it stack or heap as my physical mem is only 2Gb *( so this is the actual problem or some other factors also govern this mem allocation ??)*

4- Is there any possible workaround where i can allocate a memory of size 10^9 on a 2gig machine( I know allocating a array or mem area this much big is neither good algo design nor efficient but i just want know the limits.)

5- any better solution for allocating this much memory ( i mean should i use 2 small arrays/heap mem instead of one big chunk)
**(NOTE:Point 4 and 5 are two different approaches i would appreciate suggestion for both the approaches)**

Many thanks
P.S forgive me if i am being novice ..

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there's a more memory-efficient algorithm!

Comment: Alternative: make a file on disk to replace memory (it'll be slower but it'll work up to the size of the disk (1000Gb?)).

Comment: Do you really need 1 billion `long long int`s (that's 8 GB in-memory)? Please tell us what you're trying to achieve (also in a 32-bit environment, a process can't address that much memory).

Comment: I just need to allocate 10^9 integer elements(unsigned long will do i guess). i was trying to generate prime numbers till 10^9 using 'Sieve of Eratosthenes'. --> Then i just got entangled into this problem and actually want to know the limitation that govern this (which now appears more fascinating to me)..

Comment: @pmg Can you please explain that or point me to some source for your suggestion.. many thanks

Comment: @abhi: replace array indexing by [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html). Instead of `a[42] = a[42000000];` do `int tmp; fseek(stream, 42000000 * sizeof tmp, SEEK_SET); fread(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, stream); fseek(stream, 42 * sizeof tmp, SEEK_SET); fwrite(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, stream);`

Comment: You're trying to generate a *billion prime numbers*?  Using Eratosthenes?  You'll hit the limit of what `unsigned long long` can represent *long* before you'll generate that many values.

Comment: @JohnBode No i am trying to generate prime numbers between 2 to 10^9..

Comment: @abhi - then you aren't going to need to allocate an array that large, because there are much fewer than 10^9 prime numbers between 2 and 10^9.  You might want to dynamically allocate a much smaller array initially, and then resize it as necessary.  Give me some time to womp up an example and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: abhi, if you need a list of 1 billion ints, that's a very naive Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation. For one you can immediately throw out all even numbers, and under 10^9, there are approximately 50.8 million primes, which,  if you were just holding integers, you could use 32-bit signed ints (just regular `int` or `int32` on x86 machines). 50.8 million 32-bit integers would take up more like ~200 MB memory.

Comment: @abhi For the sieve, you need only one _bit_ per number. And it's very easy to leave out the even numbers, which brings the sieve down to about 60MB.

Comment: @JohnBode i have already coded for a working Sieve of Eratosthenes algo and used it many a times to get prime numbers. My understanding was that the algo requires to count and mark nummbers till n(n being 10^9 here) so thats why i tried allocating a array so big.

Comment: @abhi You absolutely should not be using 8 bytes per number; each number only needs two states.  You should look into bit manipulation and implement it with one bit per number, so 10^9 bits instead of 10^9 longs.

Comment: abhi - like Daniel says, you can use bits to represent values in the integer (i.e. bit #40 represents 40, if you start at 1), and you can mark it with a 0 because it's an even. You don't have to store the actual number.

Comment: @birryree got that . i guess my implementaion of the algo is very naive. i will try improving it and post the code here for suggestions. Many thanks for pointing out th eproblems and for the suggestion

Comment: you are using 32 or 64 bits per flag when one will do. But all the discussion of the sieve is off topic from the question which is about memory allocation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yep i will improve my implementation for the same. But     what i wanted to know is about the memory allocation limitation and how it works (on stack, heap and global area) if possible. i have some idea but if someone could put some light on that. that will be very good ..many thanks

Comment: @abhi - as a side effect of this it's pointed out that you can improve your code so you don't have to allocate many gigabytes of memory. For the actual memory question, David's answer says a lot about it. 32-bit processes have limitations as to how much memory is allocated per process.

Comment: @birryree yes i am trying to improve my code for the same. thanls a lot for the suggestions

Comment: Note that the stack size is limited not by physical memory but is allocated to each thread on creation.  On a modern 32 bit desktop OS, a typical stack allocation may be of the order of 2Mb per thread.  A running system will have many processes and within them a number of threads running simultaneously.  The stack is not suited to very large objects.  While your linker will allocate a default stack, you can change the allocation at build time, but it is generally a bad idea since it will be at the expense of other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling a 32 bit process and there is simply not enough physical address space for your huge data block. A 32 bit pointer can hold 2^32 distinct values, i.e. 4GB. You can't allocate more than that because you would have no way to refer to the memory. Each byte of memory that is mapped into your process must have a unique address.

So, nothing is going to fit your data into a 4GB address space. Even if your array was less than 4GB you may have problems allocating a single contiguous block of memory.

You could use a 64 bit process but you'd need to make sure you had enough physical memory to avoid disk thrashing when your array was swapped. Or you could find a different algorithm that did not require such a huge block of memory.